# rails 4 asset pipeline image subdirectories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I know this is probably an easy question but I am stumped here.

The application I am working on houses assets like so:

```
app
--assets
----fonts
----images
----javascripts
```

I like to organize assets efficiently to avoid a mess down the road so I am trying to break up images like so:

```
app
--assets
----fonts
----images
------icons
------views
--------home
--------admin
```

Ideally I would like to reference images like `image.png` without having to add the folder path in front of the asset like `views/home/image.png` which I believe has to be possible although not setup like that out of the box.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's possible if you manually add all paths underneath `app/assets/images` to the Rails asset paths in your `application.rb`:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
  config.assets.paths << path
end
```

Answer (score 25):

In Rails 4+ any changes to asset paths should be made in:

config/initializers/assets.rb

To add all subdirectories in app/assets/images to the path, add the following:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << path
end
```

Afterwards, you can verify the asset paths in the rails console with the following:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths.each do |p|
  puts p
end
```